# Trying use an AlertView to push to another view controller

Tags: ios, alertview

I'm having trouble programming an AlertView to push to a new ViewController. I've followed several tutorials and still have not been able to get it function properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)web:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"You are now entering a website outside of the Company App: Any links or references to other Internet sites (hyperlinks) are provided by Company merely as a convenience to users of this App." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Proceed", nil];

        [testAlert show];
        [testAlert release];

}

-(void)web:(UIAlertView *)web clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

    JBWebViewController *jbweb = [[JBWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JBWebViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:jbweb animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to retain the alertview for its lifetime.  That release will break it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UIAlertView` delegate

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

not

```
-(void)web:(UIAlertView *)web clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

and check self.navigationController is not `nil`.